# Tabulator - Unable to make columns resizable in react-tabulator

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am trying to use react-tabulator and am unable to make the columns resizable by the user. Setting `resizable` column property to true seems to have no effect. Neither does setting the table property `resizableColumns` to true.

Here is the edited version of the demo code I am working with:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import "react-tabulator/lib/styles.css"; // default theme
import "react-tabulator/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap.min.css"; // use Theme(s)

import { ReactTabulator } from "react-tabulator";

function SimpleButton(props) {
  const rowData = props.cell._cell.row.data;
  const cellValue = props.cell._cell.value || "Edit | Show";
  return <button onClick={() => alert(rowData.name)}>{cellValue}</button>;
}

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli Bob",
    age: "12",
    color: "red",
    dob: "01/01/1980",
    rating: 5,
    passed: true,
    pets: ["cat", "dog"],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary May",
    age: "1",
    color: "green",
    dob: "12/05/1989",
    rating: 4,
    passed: true,
    pets: ["cat"],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret Marmajuke",
    age: "16",
    color: "yellow",
    dob: "07/01/1999",
    rating: 4,
    passed: false,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Van Ng",
    age: "37",
    color: "green",
    dob: "06/10/1982",
    rating: 4,
    passed: true,
    pets: ["dog", "fish"],
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Duc Ng",
    age: "37",
    color: "yellow",
    dob: "10/10/1982",
    rating: 4,
    passed: true,
    pets: ["dog"],
  },
];

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    selectedName: "",
  };
  ref = null;

  columns = [
    { title: "Namez", field: "name", width: 150, resizable: true },
    {
      title: "Agez",
      field: "age",
      hozAlign: "left",
      formatter: "progress",
      resizable: true,
    },
    { title: "Favourite Color", field: "color", resizable: true, },
    { title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", resizable: true },
    { title: "Rating", field: "rating", hozAlign: "center", formatter: "star", resizable: true },
    {
      title: "Passed?",
      field: "passed",
      hozAlign: "center",
      formatter: "tickCross",
      resizable: true
    },
  ];

  rowClick = (e, row) => {
    // console.log("ref table: ", this.ref.current); // this is the Tabulator table instance
    // console.log("rowClick id: ${row.getData().id}", row, e);
    this.setState({ selectedName: row.getData().name });
  };

  setData = () => {
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  clearData = () => {
    this.setState({ data: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const options = {
      height: 150,
      movableRows: true,
      movableColumns: true,
      resizableColumns: true,
      resizableRows: true
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTabulator
          onRef={(ref) => (this.ref = ref)}
          columns={this.columns}
          data={data}
          events={{
            rowClick: this.rowClick,
          }}
          options={options}
          data-custom-attr="test-custom-attribute"
          className="custom-css-class"
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Here is the link to the example demo that I am unable to edit in a way to make columns resizable: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mwpy612xw?module=/src/components/Home.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this issue was introduced by react-tabulator version 0.19.0. I have downgraded to version 0.18.1 to get around the issue.

I have created an issue on github: https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues/286